# Beginner javascript - both "if" and "else" conditions are executed?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript. To my understanding, if the `if` condition is not met, the `else` condition will be executed; however, in my code, the way I see it is that both conditions are executed because there is a dot at the end **AND** there is space between the words. Which condition is actually being executed?

```
var result1 = createSentence(['I', 'am', 'worth', 'it']);
console.log('should log "I am worth it.":', result1);

function createSentence(words) {
  var sentence = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (i === words.length - 1){
        sentence += words[i] + '.';
}   else {
        sentence += words[i] + ' '
         }
}
  return sentence
}
```

Comment: Your code is in a loop. It will evaluate the `if` statement potentially more than once.

Comment: please supply an example of how you call your function

Comment: @Dai - that condition is only true ONCE though

Comment: by the way, what you're trying to do can be done with one statement: `return words.join(' ')+'.'`

Comment: @JaromandaX I suspect the OP is passing a `string` value rather than a `string[]` value - or the elements of `words` contains dots and spaces already.

Comment: @Dai, regardless, the if condition would be true exactly once and once only - yes, if the input contains `.` then it won't be removed in the output - I guess we need to wait to see how OP is using the function, as is, what is described is vague

Comment: I believe the OP is correctly passing in the words array, however they still do not have a proper understanding of loops, due to which they are confused why the code works and prints the correct output by looping over the 'words' array. They think that if once an 'if or else' conditions are executed then the other one should not be executed at all, and they would be right, if there was no for loop iterating over the array and calling the entire if-else block n number of times, where n is the length of the array. @JaromandaX

Comment: @Dai please check my comment above

Comment: @Link - so, you think the OP has no clue how loops work, has passed in an array of words, and expects what? one `.` and one space?

Comment: Yes sir!  However, I believe are not expecting a '.' and a space, instead they are trying to understand why the function is able to correctly add in '.'  or  space depending on the words array. The problem is that the way they framed the question , their query itself isn't clear, but I think they didn't come up with the code in the question themselves instead from some other source and are trying to understand how it works or why it is working correctly to be precise. @JaromandaX

Comment: This is what they have specified in their question: "In my code, the way I see it is that both conditions are executed because there is a dot at the end AND there is space between the words. Which condition is actually being executed?" But, the thing is that both conditions are executed because the OP is looping over the array, that is why there is a space between the words and a '.' at the very end.

Comment: Sorry guys, I totally forgot to add the part where I call the function. I have edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, if and else conditions are only executed on an 'either / or' basis. Both if and else conditions cannot be executed in the same iteration, or in one function call.

However, in the code that you have shared there is a for loop which is iterating through the 'words' array and that is probably the reason you are getting confused.

for loop essentially calls whatever is inside the loop for n number of times until the end condition isn't met. In this case, it is as long as words array has any more elements after the current element.

So, if your words array has 2 words, the for loop will call the inner if and else statement block 2 times:

1. The first time because value of 'i' will be 0 which is less than words.length (words.length is 2 therefore words.length-1 is 1), your else condition will be called.
2. The second time, because the value of i is equal to the length of words array - 1 (which is 1) , the if condition is satisfied and if will be executed.

```js
words = ['Hello', 'world']

var sentence = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (i === words.length - 1) {
      console.log('if condition: ', words[i]);
      sentence += words[i] + '.';
    } else {
      console.log('else condition: ', words[i]);
      sentence += words[i] + ' ';
    }
  }
  
  console.log(sentence);
```

**The above code works in the same way as the below code:**

```js
 words = ['Hello', 'world']

function ifElseBlock() {
  if (i === words.length - 1) {
    console.log('if condition: ', words[i]);
    sentence += words[i] + '.';
  } else {
    console.log('else condition: ', words[i]);
    sentence += words[i] + ' ';
  }
}

var sentence = '';
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  ifElseBlock();
}
console.log(sentence);
```

In both the cases as we can see, the for loop is executed two times because words array has 2 elements.

**I believe the below code will clarify it further:**

```js
const words = ['hello', 'world']

let sentence = '';

  if (0 === words.length - 1) {
    sentence += words[1] + '.';
  } else {
    sentence += words[0] + ' ';
  }

console.log(sentence)
```

This time only the else condition is executed because I'm not using  loop to iterate over the words array, instead I have hardcoded 0 inside the if condition and comparing it to words.length-1 which will be 1 because length of words array is 2.

Comment: Thank you! that made a lot more sense

Comment: If this helped, you should probably select it as answer in order to close the question so it will help others in the future.